# Trying to do a foreach loop that displays colors

Tags: .net

My objective is below with the code i have that isnt working.

```
string[] colors = {"red", "blue", "green", "pink"};
```

outputs all elements in the colors array, using a foreach loop

```
namespace Loop
{
 class ForEachLoop
 {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        char[] Colors = { 'R', 'B', 'G', 'P', };

        foreach (char ch in Colors)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ch);
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: And what is not working?

Comment: Got it to work by doing
{

    Console.WriteLine("Color array:");

    string[] color = { "Red", "Blue", "Green", "Pink" };


    foreach (string value in color)


        Console.WriteLine(value);
}

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    string[] colors = { "red", "blue", "green", "pink" };
    ShowColors(colors);
    char[] Colors = { 'R', 'B', 'G', 'P', };
    ShowColors(Colors);

public void ShowColors<T>(T[] colours)
{
    foreach (var ch in colours)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ch);
    }
}
```